# Using a configuration file with a compiled Go program

Tags: json, go, config

I have a Go application using a `config.json` file to get some information. When doing a `go run main.go` it works but when I'm compiling the application into an executable I have the error `open config.json: no such file or directory`.

My code is:

```
func main() {
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./config.json")
        check(err)

        var config config
        err = json.Unmarshal(data, &config)
        check(err)
}
```

I also have tried `ioutil.ReadFile("config.json")` and it does not work. `check(err)` and the `config` structure are in the `main.go`, the problem does not come from here.

`main.go`, `config.json` and the executable are in the same directory.

What should I do to be able to use the `config.json` file once the program is compiled?

Comment: Where is your config.json located?

Comment: @fl0cke Everything is in the same directory, I've added the information to the post.

Comment: Always make a way to find config files via a full path. A path relative to your source files has no meaning when deployed to another system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your config file is probably not in the working directory you have started your application in.
But hardcoding the path to the file is not the best of practices.

### Approach #1: Command-line argument

Use the [`flag`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package to pass the path to your config file as a command-line flag:

```
var filename = flag.String("config", "config.json", "Location of the config file.")

func main() {
        flag.Parse()
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*filename)
        check(err)

        var config config
        err = json.Unmarshal(data, &config)
        check(err)
}
```

Start the application with `./application -config=/path/to/config.json` (depends on your platform).

---

### Approach #2: Environment variable

Use the [`os`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/) package to read the path from your system environment.

```
func main() {
        filename := os.Getenv("PATH_TO_CONFIG")
        if filename == "" {
          filename = "config.json"
        }

        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        check(err)

        var config config
        err = json.Unmarshal(data, &config)
        check(err)
}
```

Set the environment variable `export PATH_TO_CONFIG=/path/to/config.json` (depends on your platform) and start the application.

Both approaches will attempt to find `config.json` in the working directory if no path was provided to the application.

Comment: @Volker Good suggestion. Added a second paragraph to my answer.

Comment: imho I would say that using homedir hidden file like ~/.myappconfig and prompt user for information to put in it when not present could be a good practice too, depending on usage context. Achievable with https://github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir

Answer (score 4):

Depending on whether you use `go install <your_package>` or `go build <your_package>`, your final executable will end up in different location.

If you are using `go build <your_package>`, your executable will be located in the folder where you invoked the command. IOW, it will likely work if your run `go build <your_package>` in the folder that contains your `main.go` and `config.json`.

If you use `go install <your_package>`, your executable will be located in your `$GOPATH/bin`. In that case, you will have to update the argument to your `ioutil.ReadFile()` function call accordingly.

The better approach is to pass the file location of your `config.json` as an argument to your executable, instead of hard-coding it.