# Build golang including firebase credential file .json

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, go-build

I've written an Golang program designed to is parse a scv file and upload data to FireStore, this program was build to share with people who just write scv path to upload info.

I'm using this to use firebase-admin:

```
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
```

This approach works fine when I do:

```
$ go run main.go
```

but when I build the project and execute the binary I got this:

```
$ cannot read credentials file: open firebase-config.json: no such file or directory
```

I did [read this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419263/using-a-configuration-file-with-a-compiled-go-program) but it means share *firebase-config.json* too,
the idea of this Go program is just share the executable without any doc else.

Is there a way to build the program including the json or authenticate firebase-admin using json directly like this?:

```
opt := option.WithCredentials({< authentication json >})
```

I have no found documentation or examples using this method *WithCredential*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to solve this but this is the way I did it:

1. I decided to place this script executable into */opt/< dir-name >/bin*
2. I wrote an extra function which creates the auth .json  */opt/< dir-name >/auth.json*
3. All the script executes using this */opt/< dir-name >/auth.json* file
4. I write another func which deletes the *auth.json* when the execution ends

So, now I can do this:

```
var file string = "/opt/< dir-name >/auth.json" 
sa := option.WithCredentialsFile(file)
```

Now I can share this script with the directive "Install into **/opt/< dir-name>/bin** and add this to your **$PATH**"

Answer (score 1):

For me, I use $GOPATH to fix this issue

1. For example my $GOPATH is **/home/Frank/work**
2. I put my .json file at **/home/Frank/work/myfile.json**
3. I change my code to

   opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("/home/Frank/work/myfile.json")

And somehow it works. :D

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this exact issue with `firebase-admin` when trying to move my Google Cloud Functions written with Node to Google Cloud Run (GCR) using Go. Specifically, the error **Error initializing app: cannot read credentials file: open ./firebase.json: no such file or directory**

I'm not sure why, but when I pushed my container to GCR, the JSON file was lost and I was unable to connect to `firebase-admin`. I'm guessing it's much like you're saying, that Go programs, in theory, should be self-contained.

I believe I found a solution to this problem that suits my needs, I hope it helps you.

```golang
opt := option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(`{"some": "json"}`))
```

This does mean shoving a JSON file into one string, which absolutely should not work in all situations. However, with how small the *firebase.json* files generally are, It should be OK for this use case IMO.

Links that lead me down this path, left at the end in case these links change or break:

- https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/293 (Suggestion to use a byte array)
- https://code-review.googlesource.com/c/google-api-go-client/+/33410 (code review for the suggestion)
- https://code-review.googlesource.com/c/google-api-go-client/+/33410/4/option/option_test.go#51 (test file showing the implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding credentials to your code is not safe, the info can be leaked through your app or source code.

Instead, use up the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as described in the [Firebase setup documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup):

> You can either set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, or you can explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code. The first option is more secure and is strongly recommended.

### Step 1: Remove WithCredentialsFile() call

Since the environment variable will be automatically used, you do not need to specifically load the credentials file, just call `NewApp()`:

```
app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
}
```

### Step 2: Set environment variable

Set the environment variable before running the code:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./conf/solarsink-firebase-adminsdk.json"
$ go run .
```

If you are using VSCode you can also add this environment variable to `launch.json`:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "args": [
                "-test.run",
                "TestStatus"
            ],
            "env": {
                "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "./conf/solarsink-firebase-adminsdk.json"
              }
        }

    ]
```